Which Formula One race track is this?

Took a screenshot from a podcast where there was a wall of F1 Grand Prix tracks behind the host. I was able to identify all tracks except this one inside the red box I've highlighted. I assume that is yet another Track used in F1 because the others around it are. It could also be from a different motorsport as the YouTube channel covers many of them. But I have no idea. Can someone help me identify it?
For reference the screenshot is from this YouTube video below: 



That's the Hanoi Circuit in Vietnam, which was intended to host the Vietnam Grand Prix starting in 2020. It was cancelled that year as a result of the COVID-19 pandemic, and the 2021 edition was cancelled after one of the race's main stakeholders, Nguyễn Đức Chung, was arrested for (unrelated) corruption charges. The race has not been re-added to the calendar since.
Your confusion is therefore understandable - the track was intended to host a Formula One race, but never actually has (and likely never will).

That's unfortunate, looks like a nice technical circuit that drivers would have liked. Thank you for the answer.

@LokeshVeerappan if you wanted to drive the circuit yourself, you can get a copy of F1 2020, it was released pending the race that was supposed to happen in Hanoi
